# Add leading zero only if exist with php

Tags: php, string

I want to add leading zero to a variable to obtain a 6 digits string.
I use this code

```
 echo str_pad( $var, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . str_pad( $var2, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

It's alright but if $var or $var2 is empty, the result is **000000**

If $var or $var2 don't exist, the result of str_pad must be empty for me

I can use

```
if( $var ){
    $test1 = str_pad( $var, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}
if( $var2 ){
    $test1 .= str_pad( $var2, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
}
echo $test1;
```

I just want to know if that code can be much clean or simplier.

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried another solution:

```
function addZero( $number, $length ){
    if( !$number ){ return false; }
    return str_pad( $number, $length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

and just

```
echo addZero( $var, 6) . addZero( $var2, 5);
```

Ugly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
$result = "";
$result .= $var  ? str_pad( $var, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) : null;
$result .= $var2 ? str_pad( $var2, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) : null;
```

It's really the same thing only written a bit more compactly (it does make sure that `$result` is always defined though). I would definitely not recommend trying to make the code slightly shorter at the cost of making it much harder to read.

If you had an unknown or known but large number of variables to process then there would be better solutions. But for just two, hardcoding like this is fine.

Comment: Yes, good solution. You're right, i don't have a lot of variable so both are good. I made an edit to my question with another solution who seems to be great (if adding another function is not too ugly ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can cram a ternary operation into the `str_pad()` calls to substitute zero length if the var is empty, but it is a bit ugly.  Inside each `str_pad()` call, the expression `!empty($var) ? 6 : 0` will supply a padding length of 6 if the variable isn't empty or 0 if it is, resulting in no output for empty variables.

```
echo str_pad($var1, (!empty($var1) ? 6 : 0), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . str_pad($var2, (!empty($var2) ? 6 : 0), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$var1 = "ok";
$var2 = "";
// $var2 excluded
// 0000ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary form. (condition) ? (true return value) : (false return value), which cleans up the code slightly.  So your code becomes:

```
$test1 = ($var ? str_pad( $var, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) : '');
$test1 .= ($var2 ? str_pad( $var2, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) : '');
echo $test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_pad( $var  ?: '', 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) 
   . str_pad( $var2 ?: '', 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
```

works?